# graphviz record Alignment in rounded box

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph Trasaction {
bbb [ shape=record,
    label="{ {Level 0} | { First | Second | Third } | { 0 | 1 | 2} }"
]}
```

[image: graphviz output with arrows]

Could the place that the arrow assign to be alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just construct the label differently:

```
label="{ {Level 0} | { {First | 0} | {Second | 1} | {Third | 2} } }"
```

Perfect alignment!